# Why does the derivative and integral of the funcion exist (doesn't exist)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $ f(x) = \dfrac {2\sec(x)(\cos^2(x)+3x^4\cos(3x^2))}{3x^3(1+3x^2)} $, I know that $f(x)$ is not defined in $x=0$. And it is not defined in $ {k\fracπ2:k∈Z}$ either (thanks Git Gud)
 And i understood the fact that the domain of a derivative must be a subset of f's domain. But I also have this question:

There is a theorem which says: "If f has a derivative, f is continuous." That is the same as "If f is not continuous, then it doesnt have a derivative." Would that be a valid argument to say that this function doesn't have a derivative?

Also, is it true that the integral of f doesn't exist, because f is not a bounded function?

I went to Wolphram Alpha and it computed a derivative. How is that possible? (It didn't compute an integral)

Comment: A function can't have a derivative outside its domain.The candidate derivative, if it exists at $0$, is in fact a derivative of the continuous extension of $f$ to a neighborhood of $0$ and not of $f$.

Comment: mmm.. What I mean, is that, if i define the function as: f: R-{0} to R, what would be the argument to day that f has a derivative?

Comment: Note that $f$ isn't defined in $\left\{k\frac \pi 2\colon k\in \mathbb Z\right\}$. There is not argument to be made, by definition the domain of a derivative can't be larger than that of the starting function.

Comment: I see... Well, and if I remove all of those points from the domain???

Comment: Nothing changes. The domain of $f'$ is always a subset of the domain of $f$.

Comment: I think Trux is asking how to argue that the function has a derivative inside its domain. (this would follow from product rule, chain rule etc.)

Comment: it confuses me the fact of how to define f in order for it to have a derivative. And it also confuses me that I wolphram alpha computed a derivative.

Comment: This function has asymptotes at its singularities  and so cannot even be redefined to be continuous (or differentiable) at those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this confusion comes from not stating the theorem more precisely.  Let's state the theorem more precisely.

If $f$ has a derivative *on all of $\mathbb{R}$*, then $f$ is continuous *on all of $\mathbb{R}$*.

So the contrapositive says:

If $f$ is not continuous *on all of $\mathbb{R}$*, then $f$ doesn't have a derivative *on all of $\mathbb{R}$*.

Which is true for your example.  Sure, Wolfram alpha computed a derivative, but that derivative is not valid *on all of $\mathbb{R}$*.  If you look at the derivative $f'$, you'll see that $f'$ is undefined at $x=0$ and $x=k\pi/2 (k \in \mathbb{Z})$, just like $f$ is.

Now you could replace "on all of $\mathbb{R}$" by "all of $\mathbb{R}$ except 0 and $k\pi/2$".  But then everything is still okay, because $f$ *is* continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ except 0 and $k\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram alpha ignores isolated singularities, so what it actually computed was the derivative except at the singularities. For example it will happily differentiate $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^3})$ with respect to $x$.